# compilation error while using open mp

Tags: c++, c, makefile, openmp

I'm trying to start using open mp in my project.
I have code like that:

```
#pragma omp for
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    resBuf[i] = buf1[i] ^ buf2[i];
}
```

I included `<omp.h.>` in the beginning of the file.
Also I tried using different flags and their combinations in makefile:

```
FLAGS = -Wall -g -fopenmp -lgomp -fgomp
CC = gcc
```

Still doesn't work. Have the following problem:

```
undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
undefined reference to `GOMP_barrier'
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Compile with `-fopenmp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just having -fopenmp on the gcc command line should do: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_openmp

I'd guess your project has separate compilation and linking steps and -fopenmp is missing from the linking command line. Try adding the line LDFLAGS=-fopenmp if your makefile has no LDFLAGS line or otherwise adding -fopenmp to that line.

Comment: You're right, I actually forgot to give -fopenmp flag also to a linker. Now it works fine. Thanks!